# how to extract token generated by js script (challenge.flood.io)

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am currently studying Gatling for performance testing, I am new to both. Making the task, I have stuck on the step when I need to get a token to pass it to parameter to get to the other page.
The difficulty for me is that the token is absent in the body, it is generated by a script, so I cannot get it with ...check(css(... or check(regex(...

[image]

I tryed to get the token by css and regex, getting empty result

```
.exec(
  http("Step 5 page")
    .get("${redirection}")
    .check(status.is(200))
    .check(substring("Step 5"))
    .check(css("input[name='challenger[step_id]']", "value").find.saveAs("step_id"))
    .check(css("input[name='challenger[step_number]']", "value").find.saveAs("step_number"))
    .check(css("input[name='commit']", "value").find.saveAs("commit"))
    .check(css("span.token").find.saveAs("one_time_token")))
```

How can I get the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty clear from this code that this page is performing an extra ajax request to the `/code` url to fetch the token and then display it in the page.

You'll find the value in there (you can see this HTTP request a few lines below in the Network tab).

Note: in order to learn Gatling you should probably check the [Gatling Academy](https://gatling.io/academy/).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. I found the request and extracted the token in 1 minute!!! And I lost plenty of time before, trying to do in different ways anything with the token. I read the Gatling Academy, it helps, but in this case, I needed the idea to look for the token somewhere else